# Python 3.x pygame Rain

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to do some sort of rain-effect in Python using pygame and classes. I am not used to OOP and i don't know what i am doing wrong. The drop just freezes at the top of the screen. This is my code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
width = 400
height = 300
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((230, 230, 250))
background = background.convert()

x = random.randint(0,width)
y= random.randint(-20,-3)
yspeed = random.randint(1,5)
class Drop(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.yspeed=yspeed
    def fall(self):
        self.y+=self.yspeed

    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.line(background, (138, 43, 226), (self.x, self.y), (self.x, self.y + 10))
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
drop=Drop()
drop.fall()
drop.show()

mainloop = True
FPS= 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while mainloop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             mainloop = False
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

I have just started working in pygame and python so any help would be great.

Comment: Is this your first project? If so, I would recommend doing a text-based game first (you can go your own way though.)

Comment: Why don't you have the arguments `x`, `y`, and `yspeed` for your `__init__()` function as currently all of those variables will remain undefined

Comment: Do you know what line specifically the program freezes at?  If you put a print statement in the code for debugging purposes, will it show?

Comment: well, i have done simple games such as hangman or tic-tac-toe and i thought to spice it up with something harder but i guess i should take it easy

Comment: Also the reason it doesn't move is that you are only calling the `fall` and `show` methods once, meaning that the drop is never moved after being initally created, you want to draw and move the drop in your while loop at the bottom

Comment: the program freezes right when the drop appears on the screen

Comment: i put the methods in the loop, now it moves but it is a long line that goes down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple issues with this code, the first being your use of variables `x`, `y`, and `yspeed` in you class but not taking those values in as arguments. To fix this change your class definition to:

```
class Drop(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, yspeed):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.yspeed=yspeed
    def fall(self):
        self.y+=self.yspeed
    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.line(background, (138, 43, 226), (self.x, self.y), (self.x, self.y + 10))
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

And then when creating more drops do:

```
drop = Drop(x,y,yspeed)
```

In addition, the reason the drop is frozen is that you run `drop.fall()` and then `drop.show()` once, meaning that this code is run once, therefore drawing your drop and stopping. Instead you need to add this to the `while` loop you have running at the bottom, in fact this is where all repeating code should go in your program.

Comment: Hi @Raluca Pelin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.